# How to add large braket like in picture?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, braket

How can I make brackets like this in this picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
P(k)= (\sum_{min}^{max}\frac{{K \choose k}{N-K \choose n-k}} {{N \choose n}})^j
\end{equation}
with following parameters:
\begin{itemize}
    \item $N = 2^{256}$ is the output range of SHA-256
    \item $K=target(p)$ is the target value with a probability $p$ at a particular transverse time.
    \item $n=3.5\times10^6$ is the number of hashes per time $t=90 sec$. This value is estimated in python.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
P(k)= \left(\sum_{min}^{max}\frac{{K \choose k}{N-K \choose n-k}} {{N \choose
n}}\right)^j
\end{equation}
\end{document}`

Comment: Your MWE is not compilable. However, for large bracket size, you can use `\left(...\right)` or `\big(`, `\Big(`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To make the brackets adjust to what they enclose, you can use `\left(` and `\right)`. (Additional options have been mentioned in the [comment by Joule V](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466929/how-to-add-large-braket-like-in-picture#comment1174045_466929).) I also want to encourage you to write `min` and `max` in text mode, to declare a math operator for `target` and to use `\binom` for the binomials. You may also want to use `siunitx` in order to typeset `90 sec`. Your document did not compile because you forgot `\begin{document}` and \end{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\DeclareMathOperator{\target}{target}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
P(k)= \left(\sum_{\textup{min}}^{\textup{max}}
\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\right)^j
\end{equation}
with the following parameters:
\begin{itemize}
    \item $N = 2^{256}$ is the output range of SHA-256.
    \item $K=\target(p)$ is the target value with a probability $p$ at a
    particular transverse time.
    \item $n=3.5\times10^6$ is the number of hashes per time $t=\SI{90}{\sec}$. This value is estimated in python.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't encourage users to use `\text` like this. It is wrong. Try using your example in an italic context. Use `\textup` or similar. There are so many users who uses `\text` as a hammer and really should not.

Comment: @daleif Done. Could you please remind me why it is "wrong"?

Comment: The output of `\text` is italic if used in an italic context, like in a theorem, try `\textit{test $\text{test}$ test} `, the all come out in italics. Indices like these should always be upright regardless of context. Imo it is not a good syntax to tell the user to use one command in one context and another in a different context, it should be one single syntax. We sadly see many users who use it as function names as well `\text{max} (x, y) ` because they do not know better.

Comment: `\min` and `\max` are predefined and can/should be used here.

Comment: @egreg Frankly, IMHO this is not the function `max` which is used here. I do agree that `\max` is to be used for something like `\max(x_1,x_2)`, but I am not sure that this is to be used here. To me this is just an ordinary text, as in `\sum\limits_{\text{all Saturdays}}`. I guess without knowing the context better, each of us might be right.

Comment: @marmot -- `\text` will always follow the style in which the math is embedded (so italic in theorems).  however, even if these are just "text", they should in the math be upright.  so `\mathrm` is what is wanted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know all this. The question is what `max` and `min` are being used for here. My assumption was that it is as in my `\sum\limits_{\text{all Saturdays}}` example, in which case IMHO it *should* be italic if the surrounding text is. Of course, if this assumption is not valid, then this may not apply. But I guess as long as we do not know the context, we may be better off if we avoid strong expressions like "wrong".

Comment: @marmot -- not trying to start a conflict here; just wanted to point out that, if upright is needed, `\mathrm` (which nobody else has mentioned) is the "proper" command, following knuth and other "official" documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, sorry, I should have said that this was meant to reply to the first comment, not yours. (I am a bit surprised about the language, also given that this is not at all central to the question, nor it's answer.)  And yes, `\mathrm` is what I use in my lecture notes for this. ;-)